# Remove second password from Windows7 operation

Tags: security, windows-7, user-management

I am login into Windows7 as a user from Administrator group.
Still, I am required to type user/password of administrator for every administrative operation I am doing. So I have to type the same user/password of my user to be able to continue. 
I want to remove the need to type the user/password for ANY  operation I am donig since I am logged in with admin user anyway. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

This second password is called User Account Control; it's meant to prevent programs you run from doing things with Administrative privileges without your knowledge or consent.

[This link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Turn-User-Account-Control-on-or-off) has instructions for changing or disabling User Account Control.